# Set of natural number solutions to $x^2+y^2=z^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I know that there are infinitely many solutions to the equation $x^2+y^2=z^2$
 $x,y,z\in N  $
      but if we restrict the numbers to {1,2,3,4...n}, then how many triplets (x,y,z) exist?
Asymptotical estimates are fine if an exact answer isn't possible.

Comment: Please what is $[n]$?

Comment: {1,2,3,4......,n}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of solutions of $x^2+y^2=z^2$ in coprime integers with $0\lt x\lt y\lt z\le n$ is tabulated at the [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A156685). If you call it $a(n)$, then Lehmer proved $$\lim_{n\to\infty}{a(n)\over n}={1\over2\pi}$$

The same, without the restriction to coprime solutions, does not appear to be tabulated at OEIS. Standard techniques from Analytic Number Theory should be able to get asymptotic results from the one for coprime solutions, but I don't have the time to try to work through this.

No, I'm not fighting a duel in the morning, but thanks for asking.

Comment: Hm, a modern version of Galois!! All right, please tell us what you have not yet teached us, so that we can dwell upon those things for about more two hundred years. I kid here, of course.

Comment: Could you give me a link to the proof?

Comment: Ishan, at the OEIS page you will find full bibliographic details on the Lehmer paper. The paper was published in 1900, I don't know if it's available electronically.

Comment: @Ishan Banerjee The Lehmer paper is available at http://www.jstor.org/stable/2369728?seq=2.

Comment: @Adam Bailey Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We need to restrict $z \le n$ as $x,y$ will be smaller still.  [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SumofSquaresFunction.html) states (specialized to this case) that we can factor $z^2$ as $2^{a_0}p_1^{2a_1}\ldots p_n^{2a_n}q_1^{b_1}\ldots q_m^{b^m}$ where the primes $p_i$ are $\equiv 3 \pmod 4$ and the primes $q_i$ are $\equiv 1 \pmod 4$.  All the exponents are even because $z^2$ is a square.  Then the number of ways of writing $z^2$ as a sum of squares, ignoring order and including $z^2+0^2$ is $\frac 12((b_1+1)\ldots (b_m+1) -(-1)^{a_0})$  Now add up over the $z$'s

Comment: How do you prove the result(The no. of ways of writing it as a sum of squares). Even if that is true, how would you sum this? I don't think the exponents follow any well defined pattern.

Comment: @IshanBanerjee:  the proof comes from Fermats theorem on which primes are the sum of two squares [the ones that are 4n+1] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares) then from the [Brahmagupta-Fibonacci identity}(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity) for combining them.  I agree it's hard to sum.

Comment: Are there any asymptotic estimates possible(in a somewhat simple form)?